# Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm new in building web applications. I'm trying to build simple web application using spring boot and mysql database. I created earlier database in mysql workbench, but I keep getting these exceptions:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

my application.properties file:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appautoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

spring.datasource.data-username=myusername

spring.datasource.data-password=mypassword

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I changed in appplication.properties:

spring.datasource.data.username=root
spring.datasource.data.password=root

to
`spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=root`
and now it works.